# How can I set UFW DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY using Ansible ufw module?

Tags: docker, ansible, ufw

How can I use Ansible's [ufw module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ufw_module.html) to set `DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"` as [recommended](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/#/enable-ufw-forwarding) when setting up Docker?

I know I can do it with `lineinfile`, but it would be nice to use the `ufw` module if possible, and with my limited sysadmin experience it's not clear to me how to do this from the `ufw` module documentation (and I'd rather not botch firewall rules if possible).

Comment: Setting a variable `ufw_default_forward_policy` to  `ACCEPT` is probably what you are looking for. An example of this is available here: https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw

Comment: @DavidB. that just variable is used to template the line into `/etc/default/ufw` (see https://github.com/weareinteractive/ansible-ufw/blob/master/templates/etc-default-ufw.j2) so it's equivalent to the `lineinfile` solution. maybe it can't be done via the `ufw` modules.

Answer (score 4):

This post seems to be quite old but for somebody looking for this problem the following task worked for me

```
- name: 'Allow docker DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY=ACCEPT'
  ufw: direction=routed default=allow route=yes
```

Hope that helps someone

Answer (score 2):

until a solution using the `ufw` module is posted, here is my current `lineinfile` solution for anyone that stumbles upon this question with a similar issue:

```
---
- name: docker
  hosts: docker
  become: true
  become_user: root

  handlers:
  - name: reload ufw
    command: ufw reload

  tasks:
  - name: set UFW default forward policy to ACCEPT
    lineinfile:
      dest: /etc/default/ufw
      line: DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
      regexp: "^DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY\\="
    notify: reload ufw
```